# Date comparison in '$where' query not giving expected result

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to compare dates in '$where' query to filter data. My 'where' query looks something like this:

```
function () {
    var messageStatusInfoList = this.messageStatusInfoList
    var startDate = someDate;
    var result = false;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < messageStatusInfoList.length; counter++) {
        var currentMessageStatusInfo = messageStatusInfoList[counter]
        if (counter > 0 && (currentMessageStatusInfo.messageStatus == "RESPONDED" )) {
            var responseDate = currentMessageStatusInfo.effectiveDate
            if(+responseDate >= +startDate) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is sample input document:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3687),
            "messageStatusInfoList" : [
            {
                    "effectiveDate" : ISODate("2014-08-01T13:29:26.456Z"),
                    "expirationDate" : ISODate("2014-08-04T11:40:29.824Z"),
                    "messageStatus" : "OPENED"
            },
            {
                    "effectiveDate" : ISODate("2014-08-04T11:40:29.824Z"),
                    "expirationDate" : ISODate("2014-08-05T13:01:00.135Z"),
                    "messageStatus" : "RESPONDED",
                    "userId" : NumberLong(8)
            },
            {
                    "effectiveDate" : ISODate("2014-08-05T13:01:00.135Z"),
                    "messageStatus" : "REPLY_TO_CUSTOMER",
                    "userId" : NumberLong(8)
            }
    ],
    "tenantId" : NumberLong(4),
    "text" : "some text ..",
    "version" : NumberLong(12)
}
```

As per the above document and given where query, if startDate is set to 2014-08-03, then the date comparison should evaluate to true(because responseDate is 2014-08-04T11:40:29.824Z and  responseDate is greater than startDate). But it is not happening so. The comparison operator evaluates to false.

Comment: We need more information. What do the input documents look like? Give an example. What should the output be? Why aren't your using the aggregation framework or map/reduce? How do you know that condition always evaluates to true?

Comment: @wdberkeley, I have updated the description with sample input document. And yes I am using this in map reduce. But in map and reduce functions, there is some business logic which I want to be applied only on those documents which are filtered by this 'where' query.

Comment: How do you transfer the value of **someDate** into that function? Any error information?

Comment: @Wizard, the value is transferred by invoking new Date(year,month,date). There is no error.

Comment: @Manish, I ask because I can't see the initialization to `someDate` in your function code. And $where can't access outer variable as I know. I add `var someDate = ISODate("2014-08-03");` ahead of `var startDate = someDate;` , then it works and get the correct output. I run db.c.find({$where:func}) in mongo shell; func is the function after my modification.

Comment: @Wizard, You were right the problem was because "startDate" was not initialized properly. The year part was initialized to 114 instead of 2014 due to which comparison operator was returning false. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to improper initialization of variable startDate in my where query.